# Problem with Virginia when generating geoJson

Tags: d3.js, geojson

So i am trying to make a USA map and when you hover over the state that it changes colours
But for some reason when my program generates the map the path for Virginia is the whole svg element not just the state

and my json file is a copy paste from this github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PublicaMundi/MappingAPI/master/data/geojson/us-states.json

This is my code( i am using d3.js and geojson)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>US States GeoJSON with D3.js</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width="2000" height="2000"></svg>
    <div id="stateName" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;"></div>
    <script>
      const svg = d3.select("svg");
      const stateName = document.getElementById("stateName");

      const projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa();
      const path = d3.geoPath(projection);

      const url = "us-states.json";

      d3.json(url).then(function (json) {
        svg
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(json.features)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("d", path)
          .attr("fill", "transparent")
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .attr("data-state", function (d) {
            return d.properties.name;
          })
          .on("mouseover", function () {
            d3.select(this).attr("fill", "orange");
            const state = d3.select(this).attr("data-state");
            stateName.innerHTML = state;
          })
          .on("mouseout", function () {
            d3.select(this).attr("fill", "transparent");
            stateName.innerHTML = "";
          })
          .on("click", function () {
            d3.select(this).attr("fill", "green");
          });
      });

      svg.call(
        d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
          svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        })
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I checked some stuff like if the geojson given is correct with chat gpt and i tried launching it on just my brownser not the live server but nothing helps

also visually it looks fine its just when I try to actually work with the graph

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@d3/winding-order ?

Comment: i managed to make it work but I think the problem was the geojson and the shape of it